# How do you make a system that runs a different def randomly when a def is running?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game purely out of python, and I'm trying to make a system that runs a def randomly, does anyone know how?
(Not making a system where it picks a random def, instead, it runs a def randomly depending on time) Any library is fine too.

Edit 1: The def I was referring to was a function where you get a random chest out of luck (which the "luck" is what I'm trying to make). My expected output is the def to run. In this case, me getting the first print in the def "You found a chest".

Edit 2: What I meant by "making a system where it picks a random def" was a function where it randomly picks a def. And "it runs a def randomly depending on time" is a function where it runs the def by "luck"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you wanted to just make a function that will have a certain chance every X time interval to trigger, it would look something like this:

```py
import time
import random

def Foo():
    ...

interval = 10  # Seconds
chance = 50  # Percent chance

while True:
    time.sleep(interval)
    if random.randint(1, 101) > chance:
        Foo()
```

Note that this only gives you a 50% chance that `Foo` will trigger every 10 seconds, which is not truly random. To increase the randomness, you may want to make the chance of this event happening random, as well as the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do. Suppose you want to call a function `fun()` at random intervals, but where the intervals between function calls average ten seconds. You could do this like this:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
sleep(1)
r = randrange(10)
if r == 5:
    fun()
```

In essence, what this code does is generate a random number from zero to nine once every second, and if that number is 5, it calls `fun()`. Since there's a ten percent chance of hitting 5, `fun()` will be called, on average, once every ten random numbers, i.e., once in ten seconds. If course you can define any other number from 0 to 9 as the one that must be hit for the function call.